# Contact form keeps sending me blank emails

Tags: php, html, forms

I keep receiving blank form submissions from my contact form. The emails are all coming from "CGI Mailer", and have the form labels, but all the inputs are blank.

The form does work as it should otherwise.

```
<?php

$userName       = $_POST['name'];
$userPhone      = $_POST['phone'];
$userEmail      = $_POST['email'];
$userMessage    = $_POST['text'];
$honeypot       = $_POST['firstname'];

$to             = "email address";
$subject        = "New Email From ";
$body           = "Information Submitted:";

    

$body .= "\r\n Name: " . $userName;
$body .= "\r\n Phone " .$userPhone;
$body .= "\r\n Email: " . $userEmail;
$body .= "\r\n Message: " . $userMessage;

if( ! empty( $honeypot ) ){
    return; 
}else{
    mail($to, $subject, $body);
}

header('Location: thanks.html');
?>



<form  method="post" name="myForm" action="sendform.php">

        <input name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname" class="hide-robot">

        <input id="name" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name..." required /><br />
        <input id="phone" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Phone..." required /><br />
        <input id="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="E-mail..." required /><br />
        <textarea id="text" class="form-control" name="text" placeholder="How can we help you?" style="height:150px;" required></textarea><br />
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"/><br /><br />
      </form>
```

Comment: DO you mean when you fill the form it works or do you get blank fields? Or do you mean you are getting random blank emails?

Comment: I'm getting random blank emails. When I fill in the form and submit it, i receive the emails as i should be.

Comment: Check that ALL the required fields are set before tryinjg to send the mail. Someone is probably playing with the form or maybe it a crawl

Comment: I've tested the form and it works as it should. It won't submit if any of the fields are left blank. And when it is submitted, the emails come through exactly as they should. I added some javascript validation as well to prevent any spam, but nothing has made any difference.

Comment: The only way to get blanks data in the email is to be running the form (somehow, but not necessarily as you expect) without filling the fields. So whatever you think you have done to stop that (javascript) is not working.

Comment: `if ( ! isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['phone'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['text'], $_POST['firstname']) ) {
    // something is wrong
}`

Comment: So I tried disabling the javascript validation and sending a blank form, and received a blank email. Guessing this means I need to do some more php validation?